# Replace Data in XML in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

We have a tool that is used to update variables in XML files automatically. I am trying to create a new tool that will change those variables. I've found ways to replace nodes, but I can't find a way to change the ReplaceWith value under a specific name.  E.g., Replace $VariableThree with  value of 20.

```
<Variables>
    <Variable>
      <Name>$VariableOne</Name>
      <ReplaceWith>10</ReplaceWith>
    </Variable>
    <Variable>
      <Name>$VariableTwo</Name>
      <ReplaceWith>Name</ReplaceWith>
    </Variable>
        <Variable>
      <Name>$VariableThree</Name>
      <ReplaceWith>10</ReplaceWith>
    </Variable>
```

Private Sub UpdateAttribute(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal attrValue As String, ByVal NewValue As String)

```
    Dim configXml = New XmlDocument
    Dim attr As XmlAttribute

    configXml.Load(FileName)
    attr = configXml.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/appSettings/add[@Name = '" & attrValue & "']/@value")
    attr.Value = NewValue
    configXml.Save(FileName)

End Sub

FileName = XML Location
attValue = Name of the Attribute
NewValue = the newer value
```

Comment: Can you post code that you have written to get what you are trying to do?

Comment: Updated with some other code I've used in other situations.  Basically I'm trying to update <ReplaceWith> value of 10 in the <Name>$VariableThree.  I can't use a replace as it would replace all instances of 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Variables>
 <Variable>
   <Name>$VariableOne</Name>
    <ReplaceWith>10</ReplaceWith>
 </Variable>
<Variable>
  <Name>$VariableTwo</Name>
  <ReplaceWith>Name</ReplaceWith>
</Variable>
<Variable>
  <Name>$VariableThree</Name>
  <ReplaceWith>500</ReplaceWith>
 </Variable>
</Variables>
```

i just test now, it's working fine. please copy the above text and create a new xml file then tried the below code.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim _filepath$ = "D:\text.xml"
    'Load xml fle
    Dim _xdoc As XElement = XElement.Load(_filepath$)
    'get the element where name like $VariableThree
    Dim _elmnt As XElement = (From s In _xdoc.Descendants("Variable")
                              Where s.Element("Name") = "$VariableThree"
                              Select s).FirstOrDefault()

    'update the Replacewith value
    _elmnt.Element("ReplaceWith").SetValue(500)

    'UPDATE CODE here
    'update and save xml file
    _xdoc.Save(_filepath$)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update exact `ReplaceWith` value then try this below code

```
    'Load xml fle
    Dim _xdoc As XElement = XElement.Load(_filepath$)
   'get the element where name like $VariableThree
    Dim _elmnt As XElement = (From s In _xdoc.Descendants("Variable")
                              Where s.Element("Name") = "$VariableThree"
                              Select s).FirstOrDefault()

     'update the Replacewith value
    _elmnt.Element("ReplaceWith").SetValue(200)

     'UPDATE CODE here
     'update and save xml file
    _xdoc.Save(_filepath$)
```

Comment: I tried this and it did replace the value, but unfortunately it erased all of the other entries.  All I have now in the entire XML is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Variable>
  <Name>$VariableThree</Name>
  <ReplaceWith>20</ReplaceWith>
</Variable>

Comment: DVELPR, I appreciate your assistance.  I'm getting a different error now.  On the last step, I'm getting "cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."  I confirmed that the file is not open.  I'm using Dim configXml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument to read original attributes but as far as I know that cannot be closed.